# KnockoutJS - How to notify update items in a foreach after the first render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to make a custom foreach binding and i am not able to intercept the update event properly. This custom binding is called 'test'.

Here's the markup

```
<ul data-bind='test: collection'>
    <li>
        <button data-bind='text: caption, click: $parent.callback'></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the VM example

```
function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.collection = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.collection.push({id: 1, caption: 'test1', active: true});
    self.collection.push({id: 2, caption: 'test2', active: false});
    self.collection.push({id: 3, caption: 'test3', active: false});

    self.callback = function(data) {
        data.active = true;
    }
}
```

Here's the custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      //console.log(element);

      var newValue = function(){
        return {
          data: value,
          afterRender: function(element, index, data) {
              if (index.active) {
                  $(element).css('color', 'green');
              }
          }
        }
      }

      ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValue, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

I want to change an item color when its active flag becomes TRUE, but the update callback is invoked only during the init step. How to achieve this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgA3b/)

Comment: Why the custom binding here? It seems like you want to track `active` and make UI changes when the value of that property changes. This sounds like a perfect candidate for an observable property. You could make `active` observable and use a `css` binding: http://jsfiddle.net/LgA3b/3/ (or `style` binding)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker You're right. Fact is, i've simplified a more complex scenario so take this trivial example just as a case study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems in your fiddle -

1. newValue is a function but is never called or evaluated after the initial load.
2. An observable within an observableArray does not notify the observableArray when a property on the observable changes.
3. Using ' inside of an element's attribute definition isn't cross-browser compatible (looking at you IE)
4. Active in your fiddle isn't an observable and will never notify anyone when it's value changes.

Also, in general, you are mixing the concerns here - use CSS to apply styles, use your view model to control view logic, and use data-binding to update your elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/LgA3b/4/

Note the CSS

```
.active {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, main problem for me was #2